# How to slide different pages in JQM by swiping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, swipe

I'm looking for something like in my html file with following code

```
 <!-- Extra Codiqa features -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="codiqa.ext.css">

  <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->
  <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Extra Codiqa features -->
  <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/codiqa.ext.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- Home Page-->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            Header
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a data-role="button" href="#page2">
            page1
        </a>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Second Page-->
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            Header2
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a data-role="button" href="#page1">
            page2
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this first i can see page1 and when i click button it will move to page2.

I want this like when i "swipe left " i want to saw the page 2 instead of clicking button.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`swipeleft`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipeleft/) and [`swiperight`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swiperight/), in addition to [`$.mobile.changePage()`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/) to navigate between pages. Here's a simple code, adapt it to your needs.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function () {
    $(this).on("swipeleft", function () {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page2", {
            transition: "slide"
        });
    });
});

$(document).on("pageinit", "#page2", function () {
    $(this).on("swiperight", function () {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page1", {
            transition: "slide",
            reverse: true
        });
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Mnx84/)**

Comment: its a click not a swipe action

Comment: swipe with your mouse or test it on mobile, dont use buttons @user2990885

Comment: @user2990885 I'll check it, it should work but you need to bind it to `pageinit` for each page.

Comment: @user2990885 check updated answer and demo, tested on iPhone.